# Need helping running Python code in Google Colab

Tags: python, animation, google-colaboratory

I have this animation of a circle of points rolling from 0 to 15 and back.
I wrote it in PyCharm and it works just fine there. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to work in Google Colab. I used [these](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lnl5UPFWVPrryaZZgEzd0theI6S94c3X#scrollTo=QLRBwgFqdr83) instruction to try to get it working. I've spent literally the past 6 hours on it and my brain is about to start melting out of my ears.....

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML


p = np.linspace(-np.pi/2,np.pi/2,10)
x = np.sin(p)

v = np.column_stack((np.concatenate((x,x)),np.concatenate((np.cos(p),-np.cos(p)))))
v = np.column_stack((v,[1]*len(v[::,0:1:])))

def R(theta):
  return np.matrix([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta), 0],[np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta), 0], [0,0,1]])

def T(dx, dy):
    return np.matrix([[1,0,dx],[0,1,dy],[0, 0, 1]])

x, y, z = v[::,0:1:], v[::,1:2:], v[::,2:3:]
x = [i for s in x for i in s]
y = [i for s in y for i in s]
z = [i for s in z for i in s]
z0 = [x,y,z]

ln, = plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', animated=True)
plt.close()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect(1)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 15)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 3)
    return ln,

def update(t):
    if t <=70 :
        z1 = T(t/5,1) * R(np.pi/180*((t*30)%360)) * z0
    else:
        z1 = T((140-t)/5,1) * R(-np.pi/180*((t*30)%360)) * z0

    ln, = plt.plot(z1.tolist()[0], z1.tolist()[1], 'ro', animated=True)
#     plt.close()
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames= 140, init_func=init, interval=30, blit=True)

# Initialize the Animation object again
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func=init, frames=140, interval=30, blit=True)

rc('animation', html='jshtml')

ani
```

I either get a trailing circle where the previous frames don't get removed (and another random copy in the corner):
[image]

or, if i uncomment `plt.close()`, I get just the first frame and that's it...

[image]

why is it mocking me ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slightly modified your code and now it's producing the desired output.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML


p = np.linspace(-np.pi/2,np.pi/2,10)
x = np.sin(p)

v = np.column_stack((np.concatenate((x,x)),np.concatenate((np.cos(p),-np.cos(p)))))
v = np.column_stack((v,[1]*len(v[::,0:1:])))

def R(theta):
  return np.matrix([[np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta), 0],[np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta), 0], [0,0,1]])

def T(dx, dy):
    return np.matrix([[1,0,dx],[0,1,dy],[0, 0, 1]])

x, y, z = v[::,0:1:], v[::,1:2:], v[::,2:3:]
x = [i for s in x for i in s]
y = [i for s in y for i in s]
z = [i for s in z for i in s]
z0 = [x,y,z]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.close()

ln, = ax.plot(x, y, 'ro', animated=True)
ax.set_aspect(1)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 15)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 3)
    return ln,

def update(t):
    if t <=70 :
        z1 = T(t/5,1) * R(np.pi/180*((t*30)%360)) * z0
    else:
        z1 = T((140-t)/5,1) * R(-np.pi/180*((t*30)%360)) * z0

    ln.set_data(z1.tolist()[0], z1.tolist()[1])
    return ln,

# Initialize the Animation object again
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func=init, frames=140,
                              interval=30, blit=True)

rc('animation', html='jshtml')
ani
```

You might want to avoid lists and go all numpy vectors, but it's already a nice animation.